# Tensorflow .pb file extension blocked by policy - risk of ransomware?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, malware

I am working with Tensorflow models for object recognition. The models are to be saved with the .pb file extension (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#the_savedmodel_format_on_disk).

Unfortuantely, my workplace blocks .pb file extension due to risk of ransomware from the "Dharma ransomware family" (see: https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/21260-pb-ransomware).

Has anyone else encountered such a concern before / is it a concern serious enough to prevent the use of Tensorflow?

Comment: Have you tried just using a different filename extension?

Comment: Changing filename extension allows the file to be stored in the drive, but it makes the file unusable for the tensorflow model.

Comment: I think this is a question you should ask the security department of your company. As it stands, it's not really a question fit for stackoverflow, as it's more about security policies than programming.  Maybe for the security [stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?